# Cookies Not Refreshing Dynamically - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I have set cookies like this,

```
$cookies.userName = $scope.userName; ($scope.username is a variable)
$scope.userName = $cookies.userName;
```

and in HTML,

```
{{userName}}
```

The cookies value is getting displayed correctly. The issue is, Suppose if use login with username - *aaa*, cookies is displaying `aaa.`

After *aaa* logout, when user *bbb* login, The cookie value is still `aaa`, But when I refresh the page the cookie value is shows as `bbb`. But this happens only refresh, on normal login it shows the previous cookie value.

Can anyone suggest me a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: On logout clear the cookies. And in login recreate the cookie, in case if any page need to be access based on the authorization. read the cookie and based on that provide.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use

delete $cookies['userName '];

Hope this answers your question it depends upon different versions.

Comment: I tried $cookies.remove('userName'); it says - $cookies.remove is not a function. this is cookie url - //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular-cookies.min.js

Comment: the cookie is getting deleted, but the variable username is still shows the old cookie value and on refresh showing the new one.. i tried making $scope.username="null", but when login the cookie value is null too and on refresh getting the cookie value...

Comment: use $timeout where you are updating your userName it will call $scope.$apply

Answer (score -1):

> At your login function(as soon as u click on login) place `$rootScope.login= 1;` and on your login screen controller after you set new cookie place-

```
    if ($rootScope.loin=== 1){
        window.location.reload();
     }
```

> After above code set ur scope from cookie.